# JSON identifier starting with number causes error

Tags: javascript

I'm using `JSON` formatted output from an external source (so I cannot change it). It contains the snippet below:

```
"50DayChange": {
    "raw": 0.7703804,
    "fmt": "77.04%"
},
```

I need to add this value to a javascript array, and generally use:

```
arr.push(quoteSummary.result[0].defaultKeyStatistics.52WeekChange.raw);
```

But this breaks because a javascript identifier cannot start with a number (I just learned by Googling). But I cannot find how to work around this, eg. escape the identifier.

Who knows how to call the raw value in this case?

Comment: `.defaultKeyStatistics["52WeekChange"].raw`

Comment: That gives `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '[' (line 97, file "Code.gs")`

Comment: Did you leave the `.` there before the `[`?

Comment: My bad -- thank you so much!